# Operations on 3x3 matrix through matrix products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What would I have to multiply the following matrix ...
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        g & h & i \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

by so that I get the following matrices below?

1.
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        d & e & f \\
        a & b & c \\
        g & h & i \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

2.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        g & h & i \\
        d & e & f \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

3.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        g & h & i \\
        d & e & f \\
        a & b & c \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Hint: right-multiplying by the $j$th column of the identity matrix selects the $j$th column of the matrix; left-multiplying by the $i$th row of the identity selects the $i$th row.

Comment: Is the upper-right corner element of #3 supposed to be $i$?

Comment: @amd yes, the upper-right corner element of no.3 is supposed to be "i"

Comment: @amd Is there a way to backsolve matrix multiplication so that I can use #3 and the matrix $$
        \begin{matrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        g & h & i \\
        \end{matrix}
$$ to derive which matrix I should multiply matrix in #3 by to get matrix#3?

Comment: @Tian_He Matrix products are in the form Ax=B. When I know what A and B are, what's the quickest way to find x?

Answer (score 0):

Left multiply the original matrix by the following rearranged identity matrix, and see what happens. You should be able to get an idea of the purpose of this exercise. \begin{matrix}         1 & 0 & 0 \\         0 & 0 & 1 \\         0 & 1 & 0 \\         \end{matrix}

Answer (score 0):

Every one of those matrices is just the original with its rows permuted. As I mentioned in my comment, left-multiplying a matrix by the $i$th row of the identity picks out its $i$th row. For example, $$
\left[\begin{matrix}0&1&0\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}d&e&f\end{matrix}\right].$$ So, for the first problem, the answer is going to be of the form $$
\left[\begin{matrix}0&1&0\\ \cdots&\cdots&\cdots \\ \cdots&\cdots&\cdots \end{matrix}\right].
$$ Can you fill in the rest of it now?